# Django- how to establish relationships between different apps?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

(Keep in mind that still a begginer to Django) I've been creating my first Django App for a while now. In it, I have a model that represents a geographical area. This means that each instance of that model has the purpose of representing a different area on the map. This app is OK.

**I've added a 2nd app**, a reusable app, **to my project**, called ***django-forms-builder***, that can be found here:

> https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder

This app allows me to create custom forms, in the Django Admin, that work fine. But they are 'stand-alone'/'separated' from anything from my own app.

**I would like to establish some connection, from these forms from the 2nd app, to the area model from my own app, so that, as a result, specific forms can be associated to specific areas on the map**.

This is really confusing to me, as I've only ever used a single app. I've read the models.py file in the 'django-forms-builder' app, and they are abstract, so it seems establishing foreign key relationships between models is not doable here, therefore I feel completely lost with no clues to follow on.

**So my question is how to establish a relationship between different Django apps?** I feel like there might be a Django concept, some idea other than model foreign keys that I could learn to accomplish this, and that I simply don't know about.

Comment: So you want an instance (or entry) of a form (from the form_builder) for each model representing a geographical location from the first app?

Comment: I want the possibility off adding more than 'one form per area'. But your answer definitely put me back on track, and I'll from here try to work on this detail via a admin.TabularInline add on, in the admin.py file of my app, so multiple forms can be 'added' to an area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have non-abstract models [there](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/master/forms_builder/forms/models.py#L271).
With those you should be able to bind a form to a specific 'location':

```
from forms_builder.forms.models import Form


class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, related_name='locations')
```

This way you can create and relate a form to multiple locations (I guess/hope that's what you are after).

Comment: That solved my problem. Also now, when I create an area in the admin, I get the option to associate a form to it or even create a now form in a popup window. Thank you for the help